# How to disable terminal scrolling in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, mouse, scrolling

When using a program like `htop` - mouse scroll wheel action will not do anything.

How can I reproduce such behavior in my Bash script?

I guess there should be a way to tell the terminal to ignore scrolling requests. How is that done?

Comment: htop isn't a bash script, is a ncurses app AFAIK

Comment: You can do it with ncurses. I don't know what bash tools are available, but it is possible.

Comment: this may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/q/10576401/537980

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`htop`** happens to use ncurses

ncurses (and other things that use the full screen in a terminal) initializes the terminal using the terminfo capability **`smcup`**.  For xterm (and terminal emulators that imitate it), that switches to the *alternate screen*.  Those terminals may respond to a wheel mouse by sending up/down cursor keys instead of scrolling the terminal window (which you would see in `htop` by the focus-line moving up/down).  Your bash script may see those cursor keys, but not handle them.

You can experiment with the feature in a script using

```
tput smcup
```

to switch to the alternate screen, and

```
tput rmcup
```

to switch back to the normal screen.